# How to bypass caching in utils::available.packages?

Tags: r, caching, repository

I am maintaining a local network repository that is available over http. Most of the packages are taken from CRAN, but there's one package which is written by myself (call it `mypkg`). It is in development and I publish releases from time to time, and I'd like to update the repo automatically for each release.

I wrote a rather simple script that

1. checks the available version of `mypkg` over http (I'm using `miniCRAN::pkgAvail`, but the job is actually done by `utils::available.packages`);
2. builds the newest version of `mypkg` (`devtools::build`);
3. if its' version is newer, pushes it to the repository;
4. runs `write_PACKAGES`;
5. finally, checks the available version of `mypkg` again, if the version is updated, we're good.

I'm testing the script and everything is fine except the last step. The problem is (citing the man page for `?available.packages`, insertions in square brackets mine),

> [...] If [the list of packages is] downloaded, the list is cached for the R session in a per-repository file in tempdir() [...]

so I always get the old version, despite the fact the rest of the update process goes smoothly.

My question is, how to clear the mentioned cache?

It doesn't seem that is controllable from `available.packages`, maybe I'm wrong? If I'm right, how would you implement step 5? Restart the session maybe (I'll try it as a last resort)? Search the temporary dir and erase it? There's got to be something very simple I'm not seeing.

Comment: It looks like the cache is stored in file; try deleting it and seeing if R will re-build it?

Comment: Or an alternative, move your script into a Makefile using `R -e "code"` to run R twice.

Comment: Well, you know the repo name and you know `tmpdir()`, so you could just delete the file...

Comment: Looking at the source code of `available.packages`, you could also create your own version of it by changing the code lines `if (file.exists(dest)) {res0 <- readRDS(dest)} else {#elseCodeBlock}` to `#elseCodeBlock` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [`install.r`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/examples/install.r) and [`update.r`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/examples/update.r) *a lot* to install from both local and remote repos.

I drive both via [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) which uses `/tmp` so I sometimes forcefully remove `*.rds` -- even though the scripts themselves do so too:

```
sapply(list.files(path=tempdir(), 
                  pattern="^(repos|libloc).*\\.rds$",
                  full.names=TRUE), 
       unlink)
```

I have the added benefit here of knowing / seeing the temporary directory.